# Confusion related to correlation in topic models

Tags: correlation, topic-models

I was reading this [paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2005_774.pdf) related to correlated topic models. However, I didn't understand this correlation figure.

In the figure given below, I am confused about the level curves shown in the simplex. In the first case, it says that there is diagonal covariance with non zero mean. In the second case, it says that there is negative correlation between components 1 and 2. In the third case it says that there is positive correlation between 1 and 2.

I didn't understand how they intepreted it like this

[image]

In the figure given below, the topics are uncorrelated as it says

[image]

But I didn't get why it is so? Can anyone give me some insights?